# python generating sequence

Tags: python

I have a large sequence related problem to solve for which following is sub problem, an I am sure its something very basic in python that I am not aware of.

```
seq = [4*x for x in range (1,(20/4))]
generates seq = [4, 8, 12, 16]
```

How can I generate

```
[4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 12, 16]

seq = [4*x, 4*x for x in range (1,(20/4))] does not work
```

I can easily solve above problem by writing a small function, but I require it at the variable definition time.

Comment: Is `16` meant to only be there once?

Comment: As the OP on their last line tried ``... 4*x, 4*x ...`` I think that your solution would be correct.

Comment: yes, solution was incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

Your solution doesn't work because it produces a list of tuples.

What you are looking for is a way to flatten the list you produce - the simplest way to do this is [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([4*x]*2 for x in range(1, 5)))
[4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 12, 16, 16]
```

If you intended to have the last value only once, as in your example, simply slice the end of the list (`seq[:-1]`).

As a note, rather than repeating your value for each repetition you want, you can use a list and multiply it up (providing the values are immutable, or you don't mind them being the same object). An alternative is [`itertools.repeat()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat).

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
>>> seq = [4, 8, 12, 16]
>>> seq = [i for s in zip(seq,seq) for i in s]
>>> seq
[4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 12, 16, 16]
```

In case of seq as iter,

```
>>> seq = [4, 8, 12, 16]
>>> seq = [i for s in zip(seq,seq.copy()) for i in s]
>>> seq
[4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 12, 16, 16]
```

Thanks @mgilson for the iter feedback.

Comment: I would note that using a list comprehension like this to flatten a sequence is less efficient than `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`.

Comment: this also doesn't work if `seq` is a generator.  e.g. `seq = iter([4,8,12,16])`

Answer (score 0):

A variation of @shantanoo's answer:

```
[ 4 * i for s in itertools.izip(*itertools.tee(range(1,5))) for i in s]
```

Output

```
[4, 4, 8, 8, 12, 12, 16, 16]
```

Really it was just an excuse to use `itertools.tee` :D

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple generator is all it takes:

```
def doubler_almost(seq):
    """
    Yield elements from a sequence twice until the last element
    which is only yielded once
    """
    iseq = iter(seq)
    y = next(iseq)
    yield y
    for x in iseq:
        yield y
        yield x
        y = x

print list(doubler_almost(range(4,20,4)))
```

-- Although this generator could definitely benefit from a better name...

The thing you get from this answer that you don't get from the others is that you don't need to convert to a list in order to slice off the last element -- It can be evaluated completely lazily.  It also can be passed a generator and it still works (although the answer by Lattyware still works in that case as well -- but the `zip` answers don't unless you use `itertools.tee` first).